# How to get name through foreign key in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, database, supabase

```
function CourseCard() {
  const {
    isLoading,
    data: courses,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    error,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['course'],
    queryFn: getCourses,
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  return (
    <>
      {courses.map((course) => (
        <StyledCourseCard key={course.id}>
          <div>
            <img src={course.thumbnail} alt='Course thumbnail' />
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>{course.name}</h3>
            <p>{course.description}</p>
            <p>Author: {}</p>
          </div>
        </StyledCourseCard>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I have 2 tables:

- `Courses` which has columns `id, name, description, thumbnail, teacherId` (that is foreign key to the `teachers` table)
- `Teacher` which has columns `id, fullName, email, avatar`

This is the code - I need to get the teacher's name through the relation with courses.

I tried to map the teacher table to get the corresponding teacher's id with the courses `teacherId` and return the `fullName`:

```
const {
    isLoadingTeacher,
    data: teachers,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    errorTeacher,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['teacher'],
    queryFn: getTeacher,
  });

 function getTeacherName(courseTeacherId) {
    const teacherName = teachers.map((teacher) => {
      if (teacher.id === courseTeacherId) return teacher.fullName;
    });
    return teacherName;
  }
}
```

When the `courseTeacherId` is passed by the calling function in the `author` field in the `course.map`

```
<p>Author: {getTeacherName(course.teacherId)}</p>
```

it works sometimes, but sometimes throws an error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I know it means that teachers data is not fetched, but how I can resolve that?

When it works, the name is shown correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You need to share the piece of code that is actually doing the fetching of the data for anyone to see if the data is properly being fetched or not.